# How to connect eclipse to postgresql?

Tags: java, database, eclipse, postgresql

How can I connect eclipse with postgresql?

I have a server which is tomcat v6.0 but I can't connect with postgresql.

Please help me, If you have a sample code I just need it thanks.

Comment: Do you like to connect to Postgres via Eclipse, or via Tomcat in Eclipse?

Comment: I want to connect postgres via eclipse. I have a web project. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try searching ? You can find plenty of tutorials. Please read SO FAQ.

Comment: You are a crypt! If you connect to postgres via Eclipse, you dont need a Project, you even dont need a tomcat.

Comment: Maybe you just didn't get my question.

Comment: @FerdinandPastor Honestly, it's quite hard to tell what exactly you're asking. Do you mean the Eclipse IDE? That doesn't need code to connect to PostgreSQL, it has a built-in database client. Do you mean that you want to use the EclipseLink ORM system in a Tomcat based web application to connect to PostgreSQL? Are you looking for help using the Eclipse IDE to *build* code to connect a Tomcat-based web-app to PostgreSQL? Do you want to use some *other* Eclipse project? Eclipse is a project, not just one thing; saying "Connect eclipse" is like saying "Open the Microsoft".

Comment: @FerdinandPastor Remember, nobody here knows anything about your problem unless you tell them. It might be obvious to you what you mean, but try to imagine you don't already know anything about your project; what would you need to be told to understand the problem then?

Comment: i want to connect the jsp to the database and show the data in the table to a datagrid view

Comment: @apol3pain OK, now that actually explains something, but it's pretty much a show-me-the-code-for-X, which as shown in the FAQ isn't really what Stack Overflow is for. What I advise you to do is: Use database reverse-engineering in the Eclipse IDE to build a JPA model for your database and a `persistence.xml`. Implement business logic facade classes to access that model using EJB3, JAX-RS, or whatever you prefer, then talk to those classes from your JSP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am providing certain link which might help you to connect postgres with eclipse

http://omgnoes.wordpress.com/2011/04/12/postgres-jdbc-connection-in-eclipse/

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Working_with_Eclipse

http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-do-connect-to-postgresql-with-jdbc-driver-java/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're starting Tomcat from Eclipse (for debugging) and you're getting `ClassNotFoundException` (you haven't provided any info, so I'm assuming the most probable error).

You have `JRE`, but you need also PostgreSQL `JDBC` driver. This is separate jar with name similar to that: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/postgresql/postgresql/9.1-901.jdbc3. You must have that jar either in your **WAR** archive or in Tomcat shared library directory.

Under Eclipse, there's also the possibility to add in manually to run class path, but I recommend you to pack this jar into war, because you'll have to run this on 'normal' Tomcat anyway.